# WCF Update Service Reference fails

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio

When trying to update service reference I get following error -

[image]

I read guide-line at many places that we should checkin only `Reference.cs`. But I have checked in other ServiceReference files, (like wsdl, xsd etc) as well.

Can this be a cause of UpdateService Reference to failure?

Comment: Are you using silverlight or something?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Hi This is WebApplication project.

Comment: @JohnSaunders What is your suggestion on checking-in additional files.

Comment: Check them all in. They were created for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are targeting the wrong framework in your project or you need to completely delete the service reference and re-add it instead of trying to update.

Check this link out

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542789/could-not-resolve-mscorlib-for-target-framework-netframework-version-v4-0-this-can-happen-if-the-target-framework-is-not-installed-or-if-the-framework-moniker-is-incorrectly-formatted

Good Luck